# How do I reverse the bottom word of a Hollow Square Pattern?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to create a hollow square pattern with the last line of the word being reversed from the original word.

Shown below.

[image: CompSci C i o p m m p o i c c S icSpmoC]

However, the output I have received showcases the reversed string being under the original word.

Shown below

CompSci
o     c
m     S
p     p
S     m
c     o
CompSci
icSpmoC

Here is my code:

```
public static String pattern(String str) {


         String result = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
             if (i % str.length() == 0 || (i + 1) % str.length() == 0) {
                 result += str + "\n";
             } else {
                 result += str.charAt(i) + "     " + str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i) + "\n";
             }
         }

         return result + reverse(str);
     }


 public static String reverse(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += str.substring(i, i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still relatively new to stackoverflow and don't use it often

Comment: I suppose you dont want `"CompSci"\n"icSpmoC"` but only "icSpmoC" at the end of the string?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: If so, this is actually because of the if statement you used. Specifically `(i + 1) % str.length() == 0`. When this condition is true, you append the original string again. Thats why there is another copy of the original string. You should instead have another if condition and use the continue keyword to skip that iteration

Comment: you could even consider: `if ((i + 1) % str.length() == 0) { result += reverse(str); } ` and change the return to only `return result;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the **[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)** class. That way you can get rid of your `reverse()` method, for example:

```
public static String pattern(String str) {
    // Java 8+
    String space = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(str.length() - 2, " "));
    // Java 11+
    // String space = " ".repeat(str.length() - 2);
    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
    result.append("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        result.append(str.charAt(i)).append(space)
              .append(str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)).append("\n");
    }
    return result.append(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString()).toString();
}
```